# gtkmm keyboard events skip

Tags: c++, gtkmm

Is there a way to cancel key_release event on certain conditions?
I try to explain better...I want that in an entry I can only insert numbers, if I insert another character this will be skipped.

.h file

```
bool on_value_change(GdkEventKey* key_event);
```

.c++ file

```
 m_TxtDiversi1->signal_key_release_event().connect(sigc::mem_fun(*this, &MainWindow::on_value_change));

bool MainWindow::on_value_change(GdkEventKey* key_event)
{

    if((key_event->keyval >= 48 && key_event->keyval <= 57) || (key_event->keyval >= 65456 && key_event->keyval <= 65465) || key_event->keyval == 65454)
    {
        std::cout << "1ui" << std::endl;
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

can somebody hel me please? Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution

```
    m_TxtDiversi1->signal_key_press_event().connect(sigc::mem_fun(*this, &MainWindow::on_value_change), false);

    bool MainWindow::on_value_change(GdkEventKey* key_event)
    {
        if((key_event->keyval >= 48 && key_event->keyval <= 57) || (key_event->keyval >= 65456 && key_event->keyval <= 65465) || key_event->keyval == 65454)
        {
            std::cout << "1ui" << std::endl;

            return false;
        }

        return true;
     }
```